# Yahoo Finance Date Numbers?

Tags: yahoo-finance

Anyone know what these period1 and period2 numbers are in the following URL for Yahoo Finance's historical data:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/history?period1=1471935600&period2=1566543600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

These correspond to Aug 23, 2016 - Aug 23, 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Unix time.  Number of seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970.

[Unix Time Converter](http://www.unixtimestampconverter.com/)